# Using ng-model with Select2 is not updating the model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I am using angular ng-model for select2 for data binding.
    
    
        
        {{number.text}}

```
<select id="e2" ui-select2 ng-model="select2.text" data-placeholder="Pick a number">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="number in range" value="{{number.text}}">{{number.text}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I am facing two issues here:
1) ng-change doesn't seem to be working, hence I had to use document.getElementByID..
2) value of select2.text is not getting updated here

```
function sampleController($scope,$timeout){
$scope.select2={text:"",id:""};
$scope.range=[{text:"name1", value:"id1"},
    {text:"namea2", value:"id2"},
    {text:"name3", value:"id3"}];

$timeout(function(){
    $("#e1").select2();},10
)
document.getElementById("e1").onchange = function(){
    $scope.select2.id = "selected";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` for populating options for select?

Comment: And to add Raghav; you could try `ng-value` instead of `value`!

Comment: Ng-options is not compatible with select2. Will give it a try using ng-value.

Comment: ng-value also doesn't seem to be working.